# Make a custom class that inherits TextIOWrapper

Tags: python, python-3.x, built-in, setattr, built-in-types

I am trying to make a method in a class which returns an object that behaves like a buffered file stream (python's built-in class, `TextIOWrapper`),
Plus, I am trying to add some more features(method) on it.

It would look similar to:

```py
class ReadFile:

    def __init__(self):
        self._i = 0

    def do_magic(self, file):
        # ...

        io = open(file)
        return io



if __name__ == "__main__":
    import pandas as pd

    rf = ReadFile()
    a = rf.do_magic("./data.csv")
    data = pd.read_csv(a) # this should work

    # a.desired_feature() # I want this as well
```

My first try was make a child class of `TextIOWrapper` and casting.

```py
class _TextIOWrapper(io.TextIOWrapper):
    pass

# ...

    def do_magic(self, file):
        # ...

        io = open(file)

        io.__class__ = _TextIOWrapper
        return io
```

And it gives me an `TypeError`:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "d.py", line 56, in <module>
    a = rf.do_magic("./data.csv")
  File "d.py", line 45, in do_magic
    io.__class__ = _TextIOWrapper
TypeError: __class__ assignment only supported for heap types or ModuleType subclasses
```

My second try was adding the feature(method) on the built-in.

```py
def add_method(cls):
    def decorator(func):
        @wraps(func)
        def wrapper(self, *args, **kwargs):
            return func(*args, **kwargs)
        setattr(cls, func.__name__, wrapper)
        return func
    return decorator


@add_method(io.TextIOWrapper)
def desired_feature(self):
        return None
```

Which gives me another `TypeError`:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "d.py", line 26, in <module>
    @add_method(io.TextIOWrapper)
  File "d.py", line 21, in decorator
    setattr(cls, func.__name__, wrapper)
TypeError: can't set attributes of built-in/extension type '_io.TextIOWrapper'
```

Is there any other workaround that could make `desired_feature()` work?

Comment: You could create a wrapper around the builtin object returned by `open` and then implement your additional functionality there.

Comment: `io.__class__ = _TextIOWrapper` don't do this. This isn't "casting".